# Java Years between 2 Instants

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, date-difference, java.time.instant

In Joda, we can calculate years between 2 Datetime using

```
Years.between(dateTime1, dateTime2);
```

Is there any easy way to find years between 2 instants using the `java.time` API instead without much logic?

```
ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(instant1, instant2)
```

fails:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Years
        at java.time.Instant.until(Instant.java:1157)
        at java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.between(ChronoUnit.java:272)
        ...
```

Comment: What type is `Instance1` ?

Comment: Just updated. It is java.time.Instant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find the number of years between two dates in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906301/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-years-between-two-dates-in-android)

Comment: Related: [java.time.Instant.plus(long amountToAdd, TemporalUnit unit) Unsupported unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232474/java-time-instant-pluslong-amounttoadd-temporalunit-unit-unsupported-unit#comment81426929_47232474).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The number of years between two instants is considered [undefined](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/time/Instant.java#l1161), but you can convert instants into `ZonedDateTime` and get a useful result:

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
Instant ago = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1234567890L);

System.out.println(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(
  ago.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()),
  now.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())));
```

Prints:

```
8
```

You can't directly compare instants because the location of the year boundary depends on the time zone. That means that you need to select the correct time zone for your task - `ZoneId.systemDefault()` may not be what you want! `ZoneOffset.UTC` would generally be a reasonable choice, otherwise if there's a time zone that's more meaningful in your context (e.g. the time zone of the user who will see the result) you'd want to use that.